# Rendering multiple Form fields for one Entity field

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony5

I have a problem using Symfony 5 Forms.

I have two entities:

- Reservation
- Menus

They both have a ManyToMany relation.
I want to create for each Menu object that is registered in database a numeric field input.

For example :
there a 3 menus : A, B, C

I want the form to generate (among the other generated fields used for the reservation entity) 3 numeric fields and type in each of them the quantity i want --> ( 3 menus A, 2 menus B and 1 menu C)

My problems is that all theses 3 menus are registered in the Reservation entity as “menus” field.

I tried to iterate over Menu objects to add fields to my form but it seems that the form only takes the last Menu and to not renders the others.

Any idea to generate theses fields ?

Reservation.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=ReservationRepository::class)
 */
class Reservation
{
...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Menu::class, mappedBy="reservation")
     */
    private $menus;
}
```

Menu.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=MenuRepository::class)
 */
class Menu
{
...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity=Reservation::class, inversedBy="menus")
     */
    private $reservation;
...
}
```

ReservationType.php

```
class ReservationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('firstName', null, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'custom-input form-control-lg',
                    'placeholder' => 'First name'
                ],
                'label' => false
            ])
            ->add('lastName', null, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'custom-input form-control-lg',
                    'placeholder' => 'Last name'
                ],
                'label' => false
            ])
            ->add('phoneNumber', null, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'custom-input form-control-lg',
                    'placeholder' => 'Phone number'
                ],
                'label' => false
            ])
            ->add('paymentMethod', ChoiceType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'form-control-lg'
                ],
                'placeholder' => 'Payment method',
                'choices' => [
                    "LYDIA" => true,
                    "CASH" => true
                ],
                'label' => false
            ])
        ;
    }
```

What I've tried with the form so far

AppController.php

```
<?php
#[Route('/', name: 'home')]
public function index(TableRepository $tableRepository, MenuRepository $menuRepository, Request $request): Response
{
    //...

    $form = $this->createForm(ReservationType::class, $reservation);
    $menus = $menuRepository->findAll();

    //...

    foreach ($menus as $menu) {
        $form->add('menus', TextType::class, [
            'attr' => [
                'placeholder' => 'Menu "' . $menu->getName() . '"',
                'class' => 'custom-input form-control-lg'
            ],
            'label' => false
        ]);
    }

    //...

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // $reservation = $form->getData();
        dump($reservation);
        return $this->redirectToRoute('home');
    }
}
```

What I get after the rendering (with 3 registered menus) :
[Result after rendering the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeRUE.png)

After submitting the Form, I get this error (I understand that it is not the intented object but i thought i could create the Menu object after the submit) : [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXvrG.png)

Comment: How does the quantity of menus get saved in the DB? If i want the "B Menu" x4, how is that relationship done between the reservation and the menu? The ManyToMany in your entities doesn't allow to have extra fields in the bridge table.

Comment: The way I've done it, the quantity of menus are indirectly represented by the number of Menu entities in the Reservation "menus" field.

In your case, the menus ArrayCollection will contain 4 Menu B entities.

I don't know if it's the right way to implement this, I'm opened to suggestions.

Comment: That's not how ManyToMany works. if you check the resulting schema created from your entities, in the bridge table (`menu_reservation`, i assume) both foreign keys are also primary keys, meaning, you can't have multiple records with the same `Menu` and `Reservation` combination. You're gonna need to remove the ManyToMany relationship and create a one-to-many/many-to-one associations between the 3 participating entities: `Menu`, `Reservation` and promote `menu_reservation` into a full entity with its own primary key, two foreign keys and a new field to hold the quantities.

Comment: Thank you for you piece of answer, I will do as you said. That solves a future problem but the main problematic stays unchanged. I mean instead of being an ArrayCollection of Menu it will be an ArrayCollection of MenuReservation. Do you have any kind of insight about getting those form fields generated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the comment thread and your answer i saw you modified your ManyToMany to two OneToMany/ManyToOne relationships, with that you can take advantage of the [`CollectionType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) class and let the form to deal with the field rendering and you only focus on the data, no need to add fields with a foreach.

I'm assuming you can also edit the reservation, so in your controller you need to check if the relationship is empty before creating the form.

```
if (empty($reservation->getMenuReservations())){
    $menus = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Menu::class)->findAll(); //I'm assuming you only have those 3 menus
    foreach ($menus as $menu){
        $mr = new MenuReservation();
        $mr->setMenu($menu)->setQuantity(0);
        $reservation->addMenuReservation($mr); //need to add them to the "owned" entity instead, to fill the `getMenuReservations` array
    }
}
$form = $this->createForm(ReservationType::class, $reservation);
```

With this, if you're editing or the form isn't valid, you only pre-fill the menus if the reservation is "new", otherwise, the existing ones are used.

Now, for the CollectionType magic to work, the easiest way is to create a separate form only for the MenuReservationEntity with a single field with the quantity and the name of the menu for the label:

```
class MenuReservationType extends AbstractType { 
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder->add('quantity', IntegerType::class, [
            //'label' => $builder->getData()->getMenu()->getName(),
            'attr' => [
                'min' => 0, //cant' have negative menus (client side only)
                'max' => 5 //if you want the input to limit the menus (client side only)
            ],
            'constraints' => [
                //here you add the contraints for the form (server side)
                new Positive(),
                new LessThanOrEqual(5)
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

[Here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html) is a list of constraints you could add.
And let your CollectionType know about it:

```
...
->add('menuReservation', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type' => MenuReservatioType::class,
    //if you have problems whtn submitting, it may be because the next option is false by default, uncomment if necessary 
    //'allow_add' => true
])
...
```

And finally, if you don't have the entities to [cascade persist](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations), you need to persist them individually, also, if the quantity is 0, you don't need to persist it (no point in saving empty values to the DB).

### UPDATE

Apparently the undelying data doesn't get passed to the children forms inside the `buildForm` class on a `CollectionType`, don't know if it is a bug or the way it works, gonna ask on slack and maybe post an issue on github, but we can work around it in twig:

```
{% for mr in form.menuReservation %}
    {{ form_row(mr, {'label': mr.vars.data.menu.name}) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I made the modifications to generate the fields the way you advised me to. That works, but I can't get the option ```'label' => $builder->getData()->getName()``` to work, I'd like to show the Menu name in this label, is it possible ?

I'm going off subject but I wonder if it's possible to set a combined maximum value  for theses fields (ex: the reservation cannot exceed 5 menus) with some configuration attribute, any ideas ?

Comment: Made the corrections above. Forgot I was on the MenuReservationType so you need to access the related menu first to get the name. Also added the validation with the constraint in the form and the attributes for the html input (never trust client side input).

Comment: The builder ```$builder->getData()``` field is null, I cannot get this field to be initialised. Can you explain more precisely how to access the ```Menu``` name ?

Comment: Inside a form type class you can get the underlying entity from 2 sources: `$builder->getData()` or `$options['data']`. Only if you didn't null the 2nd argument of `createForm()` in the controller. Also the `MenuReservationType` should have the `'data_class' => MenuReservation::class` option in the configureOptions method.

Comment: That field is still null, i don't understand why, I didn't null the 2nd argument :
```$form = $this->createForm(ReservationType::class, $reservation)```. The ```data_class```field is set. Is there any other configuration I missed ?

Comment: Added an update to work around the issue